# Why Does my Cannondale caad sr500 not exist on the internet?

Tags: cannondale

So I'm trying to find the value of my bike, but for some reason it doesn't exist on any kind of 'database' (I know I probably shouldn't be looking for a bike value off of them, but it's all I can think of). The frame is aluminum and says all the following: cannondale, sr500, and caad. It's got a carbon fork, shimano 105 rear shifter, shimano tiagra brake levers and I'm pretty sure the rest of the parts are shimano. 
Someone please hook a brother up.
Thanks.

Update: Thanks to @Batman's comment, I found exactly what my bike is. Here it is: 
http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2006&brand=Cannondale&model=Sport+Road+500

Comment: That seems odd -- based on a quick google search, the caad sr500 would be too old to have a carbon fork.

Comment: The SR500's I can find mention of are from 1987-1988. Simply put - your bike pre dates the internet.

Comment: Either I wasnt clear enough or you guys didn't read this, it clearly says caad, but also says sr500. It's also post internet invention.

Comment: Clear enough.  -1   It is an old bike.  $100 maybe.

Comment: Ok I'm done, you guys clearly aren't knowledgeable in this particular subject

Comment: The reason you got no answer it impossible to value a 30 year old bike without knowing a little about its condition. As it is not original (carbon forks, tiagra did not exist till early 2000's), unless in very good condition its likely worth less than $100.

Comment: For the last time, this bike is not 30 years old, previous owner got it under 10 years ago. I'm not a caveman

Comment: Amusingly - this page is now the top google match for "cannondale caad sr500 "

Comment: FWIW, caad is just Cannondale's tech name for using aluminum -- it stands for  "Cannondale Advanced Aluminum Design".  It doesn't implly being part of the CAAD series of bikes.

Comment: Thanks @Batman, thanks to you and a little bit more googling I found my bike exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't an exact answer to your question I felt it was too long for a comment. It will possible be deleted as your question is borderline off topic Your question as written likely won't likely get an informative response.   We prefer questions that can be answered, not debated endlessly. While this is not a typical response I hope it will interest you enough to rethink you question.  A google search led to JLA Forums.com It is listed as a 2007 and the specs appear to match your description. It was for sale in Jan 2014 for $695.  While I admit the information is dated it is a starting point. Look for other  Cannondales with similar components  in your area that are for sale. When a bike gets to be 8 years old there is little  value difference between individual levels (1.0 to 2.0 or sport model to comp) Regardless of any data base it's value is only what similar bikes in your area sell for.